# Want to increment the value of the Text Field that is present in another class from the AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to increment the value of the Text Field that is present in another class from the `appDelegate`. 
 The textField is defined as the following in the `TestClass.h`

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet UITextField *id;
```

From the `AppDelegate` Class want to increment the value of the text field each time I am loading the xib of the TestClass. have created an IBAction so that when ever I click on the button the xib  gets loaded with the TextFiled value getting incremented.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Is it a MAC OSX application ?

Comment: Yeah its a MAC OSX application

Comment: If it's a MAC OSX application why is there an 'ios' tag?

Answer (score 1):

whenever your xib is loaded your textfield is realloc it it better you store that value in NSUserDefaults and manupulate whenever you want

```
first time set the value 

if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key"])
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"0" forKey:@"key"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

 for set  incremented value to userdefaults value

  int i = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key"];  ///here is my key is @"key" while get value

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1] forKey:@"key"]; ///here is my key is @"key" while set value

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
 NSLog("%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key"]);


 set to text field



 NSLog("%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key"]); ///here is my key is @"key" while get value and log value

 self.txtTest.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key"] intValue]];///here is my key is @"key" while get value
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but wanted to know, how to increment the value of the text field in App Delegate.  Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: very first initialise the textfield and store that value in user default and whenever you want increment that value then get from userdefault and increment that value and again set updated value to userdefault . In your viewcontroller set userdefault value to textfield.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, small example would be useful as i am a little beginner to Objective C.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks for the example it is helping me a lot!!!.. Since the textField is an IBOutlet that is defined in TestClass.h, while accessing it do we need to re-create an object and do any sort of bindings?, since i am acceesing and setting the value in AppDelegate

Comment: ok check edited code. as you are updating value in appdelegate so it is better to manipulate userdefaults value it self and store that rather then using textfield object

Comment: Thanks for answer, but while accessing the textField in appDelegate, at present i am using the IBoutlet in Appdelegate as    
    TestClass *wc = [[TestClass alloc]init];
  NSTextField *tt = [wc tId];  //here tId is the actual IBOutlet, is this correct way of using it?

Comment: why are you using textField in appDelegate now?  just store value in userdefalt and access and assign to textfield when xib loaded

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, actually the value is getting set into user defaults, but not able to set to the textField in the TestClass, i am calling a method -(id)Test:(NSString*)Tno :(NSDictionary *)dict{
[tId Tno], This is how i am setting the value and currently an exception is raised.!!! Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: sorry but i don't get your point put some line of code for more clarity

Comment: in AppDelegate i am using the code almost similar to the above one,In my TestClass.m, i am calling a method  -(id)initWithNewTest:(NSString*)tNo :(NSDictionary *)dict { [tId setStringValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tId.stringValue"]];  This is how ia m calling here, but the value is not getting set.

Comment: [tId setStringValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tId.stringValue"]]; 


            in above 

              @"tId.stringValue"  is same as u used in appdelegate.h

Comment: Do u mean that i need to change it? or it remains the same as i have done it?

Comment: [tId setStringValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"key goes here that remain same while getting or set value"]];

i mean that key for set value and get value remain same than it works fine

Comment: is the key value any where related to my XIB connections?

Comment: no dear u r little bit confuse please read answere care fully i will update with comment

Comment: have just used the same key values and still the value is not getting captured in the UI for the TextField..!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(postNotificaiton) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    return YES;
}

- (void)postNotificaiton{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"changeValue" object:nil];
}@end
```

and in your viewcontroller

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtFld;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeValue) name:@"changeValue" object:nil];
}

- (void)changeValue{
    [self.txtFld setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.txtFld.text integerValue] + 1]];
}


@end
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for your help!!!. but it says that NSTextfield has no visible interface for setText.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do we have NSTextfield class in iOS?

Comment: the issue is not related to IOS.. Sorry for the confusion. I am not working out in IOS..

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is count the number of times you have loaded TestClass from a xib you could override awakeFromXib and increment a static counter in there.

Then set the text in your textview to the value of the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't interacted with Mac OSX applications, but to give you an idea, create a `static` variable in `TestClass` and whenever you load the XIB, increments the static variable and display in textfield. You can also use `Singleton` design pattern to handle such functionality.